# Node Express app freezes unless page is loaded from a new browser tab

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My Node JS web app has some very erratic behavior. For some routes, the page will load fine once - but any attempt to click a link elsewhere in the app, or a page refresh will not work. The browser will go white, and the loader spin forever. Some pages are more erratic - they will work fine, but on perhaps the 15th page load, the same problem kicks in.

There are no errors in the server console or browser. I've stepped through the app with Visual Studio debugger and it is finding the route, accessing the DB and from the server's perspective, completing the request every time without error. In the browser, when it crashes it appears in the console, it appears that it is receiving a tiny bit of markup - just `<html><title>....</title><body></body></html>` but nothing else.

When this happens, restarting the Node server has no effect. The only solution is to open a new browser tab, and make the request again - which works 100% of the time. Can anybody explain this behavior, and how to approach diagnosing the issue?

The app is hosted locally, using mysql, express, express-myconnection and ejs libraries. The basic structure of the app is something like this:

```
app.use(myConnection(mysql, dbOptions, "pool"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
var scraper = require("./routes/scraper");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var session = require("express-session");
app.use(cookieParser("keyboard cat"));
app.use(
   session({
      secret: "keyboard cat",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
   })
);

app.get("/siteReview/(:id)", function(req, res, next) {
   const sourceId = req.params.id;
   req.getConnection(function(error, conn) {
      conn.query(`select website_data from orgs where id = ` + sourceId, function(err, rows) {
         if (err) throw err;
         res.render("siteReview", {
            title: "Site review",
            orgId: sourceId,
            websiteData: JSON.parse(rows[0].website_data)
         }); 
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest you open the Chrome developer tools and look at the network tab.  Then, look for some sort of request from the browser to your  server that did not finish and is still open, waiting for completion.

Comment: FYI, the one request handler you  show has NO error handling at all.  So, if there's an error in either `req.getConnection()` or `con.query()`, nothing gets sent to the browser and that request handler just sits there, eventually timing out.  You should handle ALL errors on your server and send some sort of error status (probably 5xx) ANY time your server has an error.  `if (err) throw err` should NEVER be used inside a plain async callback like you are as there is nobody there to catch it and handle it appropriately and it can't be caught at a higher level because it's asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add some error handling to the one request handler you show so if there are any errors, then the request is still handled and an error status is sent and you get appropriate logging on your server:

```
app.get("/siteReview/(:id)", function(req, res) {
   const sourceId = req.params.id;
   req.getConnection(function(error, conn) {
      if (error) {
          console.log("error on req.getConnection()", error);
          res.sendStatus(500);
          return;
      }
      conn.query(`select website_data from orgs where id = ` + sourceId, function(err, rows) {
         if (err) {
             console.log("error on conn.query()", err);
             res.sendStatus(500);
             return;
         }
         res.render("siteReview", {
            title: "Site review",
            orgId: sourceId,
            websiteData: JSON.parse(rows[0].website_data)
         }); 
      });
   });
});
```

I have no idea if this is causing the precise problem you see, but it's a good first step to fix and make sure that no request from the browser is abandoned and just left there to eventually timeout.

---

Then, if the problem still persists I'd suggest you open the Chrome developer tools and look at the network tab. Then, look for some sort of request from the browser to your server that did not finish and is still open, waiting for completion.  It may well not be the URL for the main page, but could be some other resource or Ajax call that the page is doing in the process of initializing itself and loading all of its resources.

---

And, you should NEVER ever write this line of code:

```
if (err) throw err;
```

inside a plain asynchronous callback.  All that does is throw an exception back into the bowels of whatever asynchronous system the callback came from where NONE of your code can ever handle it.  Shame on the node.js doc for ever showing that in their coding examples.  It is never the correct way to write this type of error handling.  If you're going to  throw, you have to throw to something that can catch it.  A plain asynchronous callback like both of these does not provide a way for your code to ever catch that exception, therefore it goes unhandled which is always bad for a server.

Comment: That's helpful, and I'll put in better error handing (I was blindly following boilerplate examples). In this case, no errors found on the server side. Everything is being loaded - however I've noticed the page load is being stopped at a breakpoint in jQuery library, and pressing 'continue execution' results in correct page load. So an explanation for the endless whitescreen. Weirdly, I've never set a breakpoint, neither did turning it off work. Others have reported this behaviour, and apparently it's a chrome bug, which restoring default user settings resolves.

Comment: @Rusty - Are you using some sort of debug of custom version of jQuery?  You can clear all breakpoints in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: No - just plain jQuery. But having restored default settings problem has resolved.